# How do I share sound settings with different users on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, system-sounds

I have carefully set global system sounds (like windows startup/shutdown) for my user in Windows Vista Starter and now I see other users don't have access to the new profile. How can I share my settings with other users of the same machine? I don't want to go around clicking again through all sounds manually for each account.